# HTTP PUT Request to update arc in database, shaping the body, "center" point

Tags: database, http, put, point

I am trying to send a PUT request to update ARC row in my database. Columns for the table are as follows:

id_shape is **integer**, center is **point**, radius, start_angle, end_angle are of type **double precision**, ccw is **character varying**

And my request body is as follows:

```
  String arcCenter = xStr + ',' + yStr;
  String arcRadius = globals.pArcs[globals.selectedArcIndex].r.toString();
  String arcStartAngle = globals.pArcs[globals.selectedArcIndex].startAngle.toString();
  String arcEndAngle = globals.pArcs[globals.selectedArcIndex].endAngle.toString();
  String arcCCW = globals.pArcs[globals.selectedArcIndex].ccw ? '\"t\"' : '\"f\"';

  data = {
      'id_shape': globals.selectedShapeID.toString(),
      'center': {
        'x': xStr,
        'y': yStr,
      },
      'radius': arcRadius,
      'start_angle': arcStartAngle,
      'end_angle': arcEndAngle,
      'ccw': arcCCW,
  };
```

As a result I encounter the following error:

```
invalid input syntax for type point: "{"id_shape":"3","center":{"x":"0.0","y":"893.025403784439"},"radius":"600.0","start_angle":"110.0","end_angle":"50.0","ccw":"\"f\""}"
```

I think this is linked to the attempt trying to set the **center**. How can I form my string for the **POINT** type?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This was my bad. On the server side my function signature was faulty. Colleague had his update function intaking the parameters one by one instead of the whole shape info as a json body and iterating its elements for database insertion. The fix is as follows for those who may need:

```
    modify_arc : async function(id_shape, info_shape){
    center = info_shape['center'];
    radius = info_shape['radius'];
    startAngle = info_shape['startAngle'];
    endAngle = info_shape['endAngle'];
    ccw = info_shape['ccw'];
    const result = await send_query("UPDATE arc SET center = $2, radius = $3, " + 
        "start_angle = $4, end_angle = $5, ccw = $6 WHERE id_shape = $1", 
        [id_shape, center, radius, startAngle, endAngle, ccw]);
    return(result);

},
```